# Intellij show port numbers when running multiple apps in the Run Dashboard

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, run-dashboard

Previously when running applications the Run dashboard IntelliJ would display the port number next to the application Run Configuration name.

See the below screenshot.  I was expecting TracingAppA to say `TracingAppA:8001` but it just says TracingAppA.

[image]

I can find the port number by searching the logs but would prefer it to be displayed next to the application name.  Whats happened here has the defaults been changed?  If so how do I change them back?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug since IntelliJ v2019. The below steps will show ports again (for Spring Boot applications)

1. Go to Run -> Edit Configurations...
2. In the left tree, expand Spring Boot node and choose you Spring boot app
3. In the right panel, add the below (to the end) of your VM options:

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=app_port_here

Not that you have to change `app_port_here`, and the port is unique per spring boot application.

Comment: Is this bug still open? I have a more recent version of IntelliJ but with the same issue: Build #IU-213.5744.223, built on November 27, 2021

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.4 and this bug is still relevant, but this solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210665
You'll have to wait to get the port number back.